# How do I export data from MySql Workbench to CSV using a query (without using export wizard)

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am new to `Mysql workbench`, How do I export data from `MySql Workbench` to `CSV` using a query (without using export wizard).

I need a `Mysql workbench` query to convert select query output data to csv file format using MySql workbench query (not using export wizard option in Mysql workbench).

I tried `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` method, but no luck, got the following error:

`"Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'ilsnapgen'@'%' (using password: YES)   0.360 sec"`

Here is my query:

```
SELECT ITEM,COMPANY
INTO OUTFILE './file.txt'
FROM PRODUCT;
```

Please help me out. I need a query to convert data from `MySQL` workbench to csv.